# Save password plotly in Keychain mac osx

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, keychain, plotly

I'm working with ployly and I wondered if it's possible to save your plotly user and password in a keychain like it's possible with aws.

Now I need to include my user and password in my code files like :

```
import plotly.plotly as py
py.sign_in('xxxx', 'yyyyyy')
```

I think saving my user and password in a keychain would be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you won't want to have your credentials stored in plaintext and especially not in your source files.

A good practice is to store them instead in environment variables that can be accessed by the program when it is run. This also is beneficial because you can have your local environment use different (perhaps testing) credentials than your server.

There are many ways to set environment variables, but the easiest is like so in your shell:

```shell
$ export PLOTLY_USER="some_user_name"
```

In python, you will need to import [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.environ), then you can access env variables with `os.environ`.

```python
import os

print os.environ['PLOTLY_USER']
# will print your username
```